Looking for old book of fantasy stories for children
I'm looking for a book I read in the early 80s. Here's what I can recall:

It was roughly letter/A4 format, aimed at a young audience, with some full page illustrations, at least one for each story, possible more.

I read it in French, but the stories were all set in Florida, which leads me to believe it may have been a translation, I'd be fine with either language.

All the stories featured the same protagonist

In one of the stories he overhears a bunch of birds talking about killing the phoenix by scattering the ashes before he rises from it because they are jealous of him. The protagonist will warn the phoenix and help thwart their plot

In another story, he helps an old crocodile get to the fountain of youth. The power of the water comes from a flower (a waterlily maybe?) that grows in the water. If you move the flower to another fountain, the first one loses any power and the new one becomes the fountain of youth (They do this in the story)



https://rickwilber.net/work/subtropical-speculations?

No, that was published in 1991, which is much later than I read it.
